# Unity: почему увеличивается скорость перемещения объекта используя transform.Translate?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Использую build-in Joystick. Обработчик контролла выглядит так:

```
public void Move(Vector2 direction)
{
    transform.Translate(direction * Time.deltaTime * Speed);
}
```

Столкнулся с проблемой: когда direction в цепочки вызовов имеет одно и тоже значение (например `Vector2(1f, 0f)`), то есть объект движется в одном направление, то скорость движения объекта одинаковая. Но стоит мне начать дергать контролл джостика по оси Y (`Vector2(1f, anyf)`) как объект начинает двигаться быстрее по оси X. Почему так происходит и как исправить?

Comment: это смотря как вы вычисляете direction

Comment: как я выше написал, я использую встроенный компонент Joystick и в него нужно прокинуть метод, в данном случаи я прокинул метол Move

Answer (score 0):

Немного разобравшись в теме, узнал, что есть такое как "длина" вектора, или иначе "модуль" вектора.

Возьмем два вектора:
`V(1, 0)` - желаем придать объекту направление по оси X направо (**→**)
`V(1, 1)` - вверх и направо (**↗**)

Вычисляем длину векторов:
`|a| = √1² + 0² = √1 + 0 = √1 =  1` .
`|a| = √1² + 1² = √1 + 1 = √2 ≈ 1.4142135623730951`

Второй вектор имеет наибольшую длину, и именно с этим связано, то что при движение право-вверх объект двигается быстрее. Для решения этой проблемы, нужно нормализовать вектор: `Vector3.Normalize(myVector)`.

Результирующий код:

```
public void Move(Vector2 direction)
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3.Normalize(direction) * Time.deltaTime * Speed);
}
```